# Flutter integration into existing iOS app running with bitcode

Tags: ios, flutter

My group is currently evaluating flutter as a possible cross-platform tech to be used for faster development of our existing g mobile apps on both iOS and Android. As part of this evaluation, we’re putting an emphasis on the integration between flutter based features and other, natively implemented, modules and features. 
To get started, we’ve been following flutter’s official guide page (https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Add-Flutter-to-existing-apps), which gives a very basic intro to such integration. 
My question regards the integration of flutter into existing iOS apps, specifically the fact that “Currently the flutter aot compiled code is not compatible with bitcode”. Our current app runs with bitcode enabled and if this is really the case, it can be a cardinal consideration for not adopting flitter at this time. Your response will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately Flutter currently is not compatible with projects using bitcode.

There is an issue tracking this, hopefully they add support soon....

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15288

Comment: Hi, Have you got any solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Me, I faced the same issue but it was solved for me by doing the next steps:

.
For the Last FLutter Version "3.3.9" in the current Time You can Run BitCode in Xcode with "Flutter Build ios" will work correctly>>
In Xcode project settings >> Only make sure that bitcode is enabled for both the (project) and the (target) and (pod) and will work correctly.